# Handling Dynamic Controls

Tags: dynamic, controls

**This is my code:
    HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
    hl.Text = "View Detail";
    hl.Style("marin-top") = "20px";
I want to handle the position of dynamic controls like label, hyperlink, textbox
but the above given code giving error.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing like this you can pass the information as the text
for eg.

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Text = "<div align='center' style='font-weight:bold;'></br>" + strText + "</div>";              
myControl.Controls.Add(lbl);


HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
hl.Text = "<Div id='viewid' style='margin-top:20px;' align='center'>" + strText+"</Div>";
hl.NavigateUrl = "~/myPage.aspx";                
myControl.Controls.Add(hl);
```